# dotnet publish single file using VisualStudio

Tags: c#, .net, publish

I'm trying to publish a single file for a c# wpf application ( net core 6 ), without success: the pdb files are always added to the output folder. It needs to be done using VS for ... reasons.

1- Created the publish profile

[image]

2.1- Added the following line to the cs proj i'm trying to build

```
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
```

2.2- Added the following lines to all the projects in the solution

```
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>None</DebugType>
```

3- The solution also has a global NuGet.config file, and my feeling is that the issue is here: if i use the "RestorePackages" condition, no error is found but the pdbs are generated. If I don't use the condition, i get a build error. If I remove the "PackageRestore", everything is ok but it affects the debug mode, which is mandatory to have automatic restore.

```
<RestorePackages Condition="$(RestorePackages) == '' AND '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">false</RestorePackages>

<packageRestore>
  <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  <add key="automatic" value="True" />
</packageRestore>

<packageSources>
  <clear />
  <add key="mySource" />
</packageSources>
```

??
What am i missing? Thanks

Comment: You can fix it when publishing from the command line by adding `/p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false` parameters, but of course you can't do that if publishing from Visual Studio.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i already have that on all cs proj files of the solution. It should work from both command line or VS publish

Comment: Not necessarily - the PDB might be coming from a package that you didn't write. See here for discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16975